# Links to http://fairytail.answers.wikia.com/ are not allowed?

Tags: support, status-norepro

Well I was answering a question on fairy tail which asked  **Who is this green guy in fairy tail?** and when I tried to include a certain link for reference as to where I copied and pasted the original it gave me this....

> Links to http://fairytail.answers.wikia.com/wiki/What_is_that_hidden_green_character_i'm_starting_to_see_in_the_background_in_some_of_the_episodes are not allowed in a red box. See picture below.

[image]

So my question is....

1. What happens if I leave this link in my answer? Will I get suspended or something?
2. Is this like some automated thing that stack exchange has to detect bad websites?
3. Possibilities as to why the sites blocked/not allowed?

I have never recieved this before so much help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Problem solved. For some reason now I am not recieving this error anymore. I was able to post my answer with ease. Although I am not sure what happened and why I was recieving this message. Maybe someone saw my question and fixed something perhaps?

Comment: I think it just won't let you post the answer until you delete the link. I'm not sure why that particular site is blocked, but it could be due to a lot of low quality content. In any case, your answer seems to just be copied from the wiki over there anyway, which doesn't seem like a great answer since that site is also poorly sourced. It would be better if you can find primary sources to back up your answer rather than relying on something that someone else wrote somewhere on the internet without any accountability or verification.

Comment: @LoganM- I was definitely gonna add more content including a youtube video of all the scenes in fairy tail including when they appeared and specifically show the scene relating to the picture the OP provided and add some additional info.

Comment: I was also thinking of shortening it too (The answer).

Comment: This is a transient issue that sometimes occurs when you paste URLs into a question or answer. I assume it's a known issue - I run into it frequently enough that I'm assuming it's been reported before. If you see this message, you shouldn't worry _unless_ it shows up again when you try to submit the post. In this particular case, it looks like your URL began with `http://http://` (that is, twice), which is what may have tripped the validator up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't, the site won't let you. You will not get suspended.
2. I don't know what caused it, but it may have been a one-off thing or you may have tried a malformed URL.
3. See 2 above.